# Cannot return a value from method whose result type is void error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I am trying to take the user input from one method and use it in another. I am confused about the cannot return a value from method whose result type is void error because "userMove" is defined as type int.

```
public static void move()
{
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userMove = scan.nextInt();
    return userMove;
}

public static void usersMove(String playerName, int gesture)
{
    int userMove = move();

    if (userMove == -1)
    {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Never saw a void method returns an int value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply change `void` to `int` as you're returning an `int`.

```
public static int move()
{
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userMove = scan.nextInt();
    return userMove;
}
```

A `void` method means it returns nothing (ie. no return statement), anything other then `void` and a return is required.

Comment: ***A void method means it returns nothing (ie. no return statement), anything other then void and a return is required.*** would be an overstatement. One can still take advantage of  `return;` to safely exit a void function.

Answer (score 4):

A method which is marked as `void` means that it does not return anything. It can be seen as a `procedure` as opposed to a `function`.

Changing your method signature to `public static int move()` should fix your problem. Your method would now represent a `function`, which has a return value.

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) Oracle tutorial should provide some useful information.