# play framework redirect not working

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework-2.0

I'm developing an Application that harvests information from Twitter. I want the user to be able to indicate which parts of their profile I should use (for example they may not want their tweets to be used) so I'm going to use checkboxes to allow the user to indicate which parts of the profile should be used. Once the login button has been clicked I intend to determine which boxes are checked using Javascript and then make an AJAX call to the Java function that begins the Twitter login flow. Before I did that though I just wanted to be sure I could make the function work. The last line of the function is a redirect to Twitter where they can login. However, the redirect command does nothing at all. Every other line in the function executes as it should. I even created an example file within the function to make absolutely sure the function was being called and that the parameter from the AJAX function had been successfully passed. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. My code is below:

```
Javascript
<input id="tw" type="button" onclick="twitterLogin()"value="Login to Twitter"/>
function twitterLogin(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@{Application.requestToken()}",
                data: {
                text: "Well that's odd"
                }
            })
        }


Java
public static void requestToken(String text){
    try{
        String prelimOAuthToken = Twitter.getRequestToken();

        if(prelimOAuthToken.equals("Failed")){
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("Error log.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write("Getting a request token failed");
            out.close();
        }
        else{
            BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Output.txt"));
            b.write(text);
            b.close();
            //Now we use this oauth token to redirect the user for authentication
            String url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=" + prelimOAuthToken;
            redirect(url);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`requestToken` needs to be of type `Result` and your `if` clause needs to return a `Result` as well.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I've tried to return a redirect result but I'm getting an error that says I can't return a void result.

Comment: Could you include what you have tried? What is the signature of `requestToken` after you tried my suggestion? Did you change `void` to `Result`? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15518399/830153) should shed more light on return values.